# Different startup directory for every Cmder shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, cmder

Say I have 2 `Cmder.exe` in my desktop

- `Cmder.exe - Shortcut 1`
- `Cmder.exe - Shortcut 2`

How can I make shortcut 1 to start `Cmder` in directory `C:\sample1\` and shortcut 2 start in `C:\sample2\`?

Comment: right click the shortcut, choose "settings" and put the path where you want to start cmder in the "run in" field. maybe the field is called a little different, I translated it from german

Answer (score 0):

I think we can refer the article:

Change %USERPROFILE% to desired folder instead, then we could edit the **config** and place our custom folder.

[Start up cmder ConEmu console in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933766/start-up-cmder-conemu-console-in-a-specific-folder/43836978#43836978)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Just add `/START "D:\your\path"` in the `Target` field of the shortcut's properties.